# WScript.Shell RegWrite fails on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows, activex, hta

I currently use the following code to modify the registry in JavaScript called from my .hta installer file.

```
var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
wsh.RegWrite("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\blah\\blah\\myKey", "0","REG_DWORD");
```

However on Windows 8.1 this code fails with an `Invalid root in registry key` error.

I've researched this, and it seems it is failing due to a lack of permissions, what do I need to do to make sure this ActiveX call is running with elevated permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VBScript function which tests if the user has permission, like this (I don't think that is possible in Javascript, but it doesn't matter because Javascript can use functions declared in VBScript):

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
     Function test()
          If CBool(IsNTAdmin) = True Then
               test = true      'Returns true if the user has elevated permissions
          Else
               test = false     'Returns false if the user doesn't
          End If
     End Function
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     if(test()){
          var wsh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
          wsh.RegWrite("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\blah\\blah\\myKey","0","REG_DWORD");
     }
     else{
          alert("You don't have permission to do this!");
     }
</script>
```

Comment: So how can I use that approach to escalate permissions as required?

Comment: You can't. On Windows, you have two types of accounts: administrator and limited account. An administrator already has all permissions and a limited account has, as it's name indicates, limited permissions. If you want to escalate permissions, you need to go on an administrator account and change your type of account. If you don't know how to do this, I suggest you ask a new question with the "windows" tag.